# Accessing schema default values

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have defined and exported a schema with some default values for my DB. How do I access default values of the schema from another module?

```
const mySchema = new Schema({
    property: {
         type: String,
         enum: ['a', 'b', 'c', ...]
    },
    ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Alpha', mySchema);
```

As an example, I would like to loop over the enum array values and console.log(array[i]).

```
let alphabet = mySchema.property.enum
alphabet.forEach(letter => console.log(letter))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is **not** possible to access **default** `enum` values from the mongoose schema itself. You will need to store the `enums` in a separate variable and use it in you model. Then export that variable and use it where it's needed.

```js
export enum PropertyEnums {
  a = "a", // set value of enum a to "a" else it will default to 0
  b = "b",
  c = "c",
  ...
}

const mySchema = new Schema({
    property: {
         type: String,
         enum: Object.values(PropertyEnums), // equivalent to ["a", "b", "c", ...]
         default: PropertyEnums.a // if you want to set a default value for this field
    },
    ...
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Alpha', mySchema);
```

Then just import the enum where it's needed like so:

```js
import { PropertyEnums } from "./yourSchemaFile.js"

let alphabet = Object.values(PropertyEnums)
alphabet.forEach(letter => console.log(letter))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define like below:

```
export enum Props {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B'
}
```

in schema:

```
property: {
     type: String,
     enum: Props
},
```

for Access:

```
for (let item in Props) {
  if (isNaN(Number(item))) {
    console.log(item);
    }
}
```